# Graph api /inbox has missing data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, inbox

I have an application that goes and gets a users messages from their facebook account, but I've hit an error.

The user in question has a thread between him and me in his inbox, however it doesn't show up in his API call to `/me/inbox` with his specific access_token.

I do have a valid token (it works for all other calls), and I know it should be working fine (I am opening it in my browser directly to debug, and the data just does not exist).

There is no second page to view, no limit or timestamp imposed upon it, just missing data.

For testing, we do have every single API permission offered, so I know it is not a permissions problem.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem. I found that using the `/me/threads' endpoint delivers much more complete data.

#### Update:

However I found out that this endpoint is not available to non-developers for the time being:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/